# jquery slidedown up and toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jquery, I would like to use slidedown and up or toggle here is my code :

```
       <div class="vertical-termekek">  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="vertical-nav"><p>Termékek</p> <li class="dropdown">
       <?php 
         wp_nav_menu(array(
         'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
       ....)
           )); 
         ?></li>
      </ul></div>


My JQuery SCRIPT

       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.vertical-termekek').click(function () {
        $('li', this).slideDown(200);
     });
    });
```

Its working fine when i am full screen vertical menu not close is great i dont want to close vertical menu,by full screen (disable function) but i would like to use jquery code when i go smaller screen (992px and smaller)
I don't know what is the next step!

If i go smaller screen no hide li class but work slide up and down
it used this because i have submenu too and anybody click submenu i don't wanna to close the hole vertical menu just accordion down

```
     $(function () {
    $('.vertical-termekek').click(function () {
        $('li', this).slideToggle();
    });
    $('.vertical-termekek li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
     });

        //Resize handler to reset the menu visibility 
       var resizeTimer;
       $(window).on('resize', function (e) {
         clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
              resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                  if ($(window).width() > 992) {
              $('li.dropdown').show();
         } else {
             $('li.dropdown').hide();
         }
       }, 250);
     });

      });
```

here is my website :http://fonottkosarbolt.hu/
but li class shown i couldnt' hide
and if i make

Css

```
@media(max-width:768px) { 
li.dropdown{
 display:none;

  }
}
```

the slidedown and up dont work (confusing) and slide up and down work on full screen (its bad for me) I wanna fix underfull screen  i'm working on 3 days and i haven't any ide.

Please help 
thx !

I changed but still not work

```
     <div class="vertical-termekek">  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked           col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="vertical-nav"> <li class="dropdown">        <p>Termékek</p>
        <?php 
         wp_nav_menu(array(
```

Please more details am not pro:S

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for this ??

Comment: invalid markup!!!!! `<p>` should not be a child of `<ul>` but `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to achieve the conditional click handling is to check the window's width in the `click` handler. There are no performance issues as it's for a click event (not something like window resize).

```
$('.vertical-termekek').click(function () {
    if (window width is < desktop width) {
        $('.dropdown', this).slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Edit: I just had a look at your site. You need to use media queries to show/hide the menu as a basic step, as you are doing. But since we should go mobile first, the default style should be hidden. Then use min-width in your media query (not max-width since mobile first) to show it:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) { 
    li.dropdown{
        display: block; 
    }
}
```

You may have to add `!important` to the above style since jQuery sets the style on the element, which will take precendence.